# how can i traverse an xml file using ajax faster/more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, traversal

i have an xml file that looks like the following:

```
<UUT>
<DKBFile>091750</DKBFile>
<part>
  <name>FL_U1</name>
  <xcoord>439</xcoord>
  <ycoord>132</ycoord>
  <width>55</width>
  <height>24</height>
</part>
</UUT>
```

that may have a few hundred "Parts" that i'm trying to get name/coordinate info for.  The amount, and the parts i'm getting information for, changes, but the traversing gets VERY slow once i'm trying to get this information for over 100 parts.  Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "PROFILER_ShopAid/shopaid.xml",
dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "xml" : "text/xml",

success: function(data){    

var i = 1;  //array traversal
var xcoord = 0;
var ycoord = 0;
var width = 0;
var height = 0;
var part = "";
var nameFound = "";

//Get Part Count
var covCnt = DKB.GetClearedPartCnt();  //Gets number of parts

     //Get Part Info
while (covCnt >= i)
{
    part = DKB.GetClearedPart(i);  //Returns name of  part

    $(data).find("part").each(function() {
        nameFound = $(this).find("name").text();  

        if(part.toLowerCase() == nameFound.toLowerCase())
        {
            xcoord = parseInt( $(this).find("xcoord").text() );
            ycoord = parseInt( $(this).find("ycoord").text() );
            width = parseInt( $(this).find("width").text() );
            height = parseInt($(this).find("height").text() );

        }

    });
    i = i + 1;
}
},

error: function(){
}

});
```

The xml file is on a local server, this code is being used in an HTA (HTML Application file).  Is there a more efficient way to go about traversing the xml file? right now, it takes about 15-20 seconds to get the information for ~150 parts.  i've timed the queries i'm making to get the part count/part names (i commented out the AJAX code), and those are under 200ms for large part counts.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing your entire XML data and creating a new object inside your loop when you do `$(data)`.

Instead, you should put that before your loop and you should see a significant difference. Here is the relevant portion of your code updated:

```
...

var $data = $(data); // Do this once

while (covCnt >= i)
{

    part = DKB.GetClearedPart(i);  //Returns name of  part

    $data.find("part").each(function() {

    ...
```